# Hello i want to know how can i use both java +kotlin both in flutter actually i want to use both languages to to create my own app in flutter

Tags: flutter

public class My Question

{    public void main()

```
    {
     System.out.println( "sorry but i could not post my question due to this body section problem"):
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Flutter apps are written with **dart lang**.

You can use Java/Kotlin and Obj-C/Swift for platform-specific code using Platfom Channel. But, your Java/Ktl code will run only on Android.

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

Flutter app code: *dart*.

Platform specific code Android: **Java/Kotlin**.

Platofrm specific code iOS: **Obj-C/Swift**.

**You can't use Java/Kotlin for flutter app main code (.dart files).**

Comment: so nice of you sir thanks  for solving my problem  you have saved my time